# SLL Secured Pages but not fully Posts

Tags: ssl-certificate, github-pages

I've uploaded a new static blog to GitHub Pages using Ghost and Buster.

Github Repo: https://github.com/paddy420Smokers/cannalogie

I've added the code below to force all pages to use https:// , on the Frontpage and Category Pages its working fine, but on Posts only https:// is there but it's not fully secured.

```
<script>
     var host = "cannalogie.net";
     if ((host ==window.location.host) && (window.location.protocol != "https:"))
     window.location.protocol = "https";
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to fully secure all pages and posts?

Comment: What does "not fully secured" mean?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sxkuAq6.png , Theres no lock symbol on posts

Comment: It should have a lock like this: https://i.imgur.com/ikA3LGU.png

Comment: Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the developer tools, it looks like you're loading something that over `http` while the rest of your page is loaded over `https`. That causes the whole page to be considered insecure and not show the lock symbol, even if the url shows `https`.

It looks like you're loading a `.gif` over `http`. If you change the url to load it over `https`, the error should go away and the lock should appear.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Dude, thanks so much for your help. That should work. You helped a lot!!!

Comment: Not to fish for points, but could you accept/upvote the answer? I'd greatly appreciate it